# tensorflow data loading csv with Nan

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a silly problem but i cannot wrap my head around it...i am trying to load a csv file into tensorflow using the tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset function....However I have 'NA's for missing values in the file and while i can tell tensorflow na_value='NA'...the missing values get replaced by 0's which is not ideal...so is there a way to change the default setting to what the Nan's get replaced to or is there a way to identify the missing values after file is loaded?

Cheers

Comment: Although this might not be a direct answer to your question I highly recommend you use DataFrames from the pandas package. Its much easier to work with CSV data and then you can set default values and view which one's are missing. Or use numpy to set detault values for your NA. Let me know the structure of your data and I can try and provide an example

Comment: @Vernon How did you manage to read in a CSV with missing data using `tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset`? I've been unable to get a toy example to work.